# MySQL foreignkey - If data is changed it should have no action to the foreign table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables.

1st table: Question

```
| id | name |
```

2nd table: Answer

```
| id | answer | questionid |
```

My problem is, that when a change is made in the question, the answer dont fit to the question. So when I make a change in a question, it shouldn't effect on existing answers.

How can I realize this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? So when your question changes - you want to make sure that previous answers still match the original question? How about you always `insert` new questions, instead of `update`. You could also use a timestamp (e.g. ValidFrom and ValidTo sort of thing).

Comment: You mean you do an update on the question field itself? Of course the answers belong with the old question. If you wish to change "question 1" yet wish to preserve the old Question-Answer pairs, you should think about adding a separate field for "Question number" and "Is active question" in your question table. - I.e. preserve all "old" questions and answers and just put the active question on your screen or whatever you do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is not needed now, the answer was given to that old question's context. You will have to add the new question as a separate row under the questions table and update the old question only if you are trying to rephrase it.

In any UI, if you want to show the questions, you can maintain another column named "isActive" and show only the active questions. In this way, you can reactivate any questions in the future instead of adding new.